# Group By first word using Lambda

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Here is an example of some data:

**Charge** (the following are ChargeName)

> Apple 1
>   Apple 2
>   Banana 1
>   Banana 2
>   Carrot 3

I need to generate a list to look like this: (Notice what i need is really to group by the first word)

> Apple
>   Banana
>   Carrot

Perhaps it should start something like this?

```
db.Charges.Select(d=>d.ChargeName).GroupBy(....);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think EF can translate such grouping into SQL, so move grouping into memory with `AsEnumerable()` call (that will download all data):

```
db.Charges.AsEnumerable()
  .GroupBy(c => c.ChargeName.Split()[0]);
```

If you actually don't need grouping, but you need only group names, then use distinct approach, as LB suggested.

Answer (score 2):

```
var list = new List<string> { "Apple 1", "Apple 2", "Banana 1", "Banana 2", "Carrot 3" };
var newList = list.Select(x => x.Split()[0]).Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to do this entirely in RDBMS, try using `SqlFunctions.CharIndex`, like this:

```
var res = db.Charges.GroupBy( c =>
    c.ChargeName.Substring(
        0
    ,   SqlFunctions.CharIndex(" ", c.ChargeName) ?? c.ChargeName.Length
    )
);
```

Note the `?? c.ChargeName.Length` part: it is necessary to handle situations when `ChargeName` is a single word.

Comment: Now we're cooking with gas!